# How do I integrate a game in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use this game https://github.com/yum650350/tissuebox in my Flutter project. I tried calling different parts of the main page but it wasn't coming up properly even though the game itself is working. 
I want to integrate it in my iOS app and want to call it with a 
function which opens a separate page where the user can play the game. 
Is there a way I can do it?
So this is what I tried: 
I called the method of the game in a separate screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: FirstScreen(),
  ));
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Go to Second Screen'),
          onPressed: () {

            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
           **???**
            }));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I don't know what to call in **??** this part since the game isn't wrapped in any class. This is the code of the game I want to call.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/util.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'dart:math';

tissuemain() async {
  var util = Util();
  await util.fullScreen();
  await util.setOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp); 
  //loadimages
  //tissuebox : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
  //background : b
  //crown : c
  //tissue : t
  await Flame.images.loadAll(['b', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 't', 'c']);
  audioLoad(c) async => (await Flame.audio.load(c)).path;
  setAudio(a, s, v) async {
    await a.setUrl(await audioLoad(s), isLocal: true);
    a.setVolume(v);
  }
  //audios
  //single drag : s.mp3
  //double drag : s.mp3
  //triple drag ： s.mp3
  //tick tock : tk.mp3
  //game over : a.mp3
  GameTable.setAudioList(GameTable.audioList1, await audioLoad('s.mp3'));
  GameTable.setAudioList(GameTable.audioList2, await audioLoad('d.mp3'));
  GameTable.setAudioList(GameTable.audioList3, await audioLoad('t.mp3'));
  await setAudio(GameTable.tickTock, 'tk.mp3', 1.0);
  await setAudio(GameTable.gameOver, 'a.mp3', .5);
  var game = GameTable((await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getInt('hs') ?? 0);
  var hDrag = HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer();
  var vDrag = VerticalDragGestureRecognizer();
  hDrag.onUpdate = game.onDragUpdate;
  hDrag.onStart = game.onDragStart;
  hDrag.onEnd = game.onDragEnd;
  vDrag.onUpdate = game.onDragUpdate;
  vDrag.onStart = game.onDragStart;
  vDrag.onEnd = game.onDragEnd;
  runApp(game.widget);
  util.addGestureRecognizer(hDrag);
  util.addGestureRecognizer(vDrag);
}

enum Drag { tissue, box, none }

class GameTable extends Game {
  //Audio
  //These are workarounds for the ios memory leak
  static var 
      tickTock = AudioPlayer(),
      gameOver = AudioPlayer(),
      audioList1 = [AudioPlayer(), AudioPlayer(), AudioPlayer()],
      audioList2 = [AudioPlayer(), AudioPlayer()],
      audioList3 = [AudioPlayer(), AudioPlayer()],
      audioIndex1 = 0,
      audioIndex2 = 0,
      audioIndex3 = 0;
  static getPlayIndex(int audioPlayer) {
    if (audioPlayer == 1)
      audioIndex1 = audioIndex1 < audioList1.length - 1 ? audioIndex1 + 1 : 0;
    else if (audioPlayer == 2)
      audioIndex2 = audioIndex2 < audioList2.length - 1 ? audioIndex2 + 1 : 0;
    else if (audioPlayer == 3) audioIndex3 = audioIndex3 < audioList3.length - 1 ? audioIndex3 + 1 : 0; 
    return audioPlayer == 1 ? audioIndex1 : audioPlayer == 2 ? audioIndex2 : audioIndex3;
  }
  static get tissue1 => audioList1[getPlayIndex(1)];
  static get tissue2 => audioList2[getPlayIndex(2)];
  static get tissue3 => audioList3[getPlayIndex(3)];
  static setAudioList(List<AudioPlayer> al,String audioName) => al.forEach((x) {
        x.setUrl(audioName, isLocal: true);
        x.setVolume(.2);
      });
  //


  var background = Sprite('b'),
      crown = Sprite('c'),
      initialPoint = Offset.zero,
      destPoint = Offset.zero,
      dragState = Drag.none,
      gameing = false,
      gameover = false,
      timePass = .0,
      heighScore = 0,
      score = 0,
      timePassTemp = 0;

  double tileSize, point1;
  double get k => screenSize.width / 5 / tileSize;
  Size screenSize;
  Rect rect;
  TissueBox tissueBox;

  saveHighScore() async => await (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).setInt('hs', heighScore);

  GameTable(this.heighScore) {
    init();
  }

  init() async {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
    rect = Rect.fromLTWH(.0, screenSize.height - tileSize * 23, tileSize * 9, tileSize * 23);
    tissueBox = TissueBox(this);
  }

  @override
  render(Canvas c) {
    paintText(txt, offset, center, fontSize) {
      var painter = TextPainter(
          text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: fontSize,
                  fontFamily: 'NS'),
              text: txt),
          textScaleFactor: k,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
      painter.layout();
      painter.paint(c, center ? Offset(offset.dx - painter.width / 2, offset.dy) : offset);
    }

    background.renderRect(c, rect);
    tissueBox.render(c);
    var horCenter = tissueBox.initialLeft + tissueBox.boxRect.width / 2;
    if (gameing)
      paintText(timePass.toStringAsFixed(timePass < 1 ? 1 : 0) + 's', Offset(horCenter + 8, k * 23), true, k * 10);
    var heighScoreTxt = heighScore.toString();
    paintText(heighScoreTxt, Offset(heighScoreTxt.length==1?44.0:heighScoreTxt.length>2?22.0:33.0, k * 30), false, k * 12);
    crown.renderRect(c, Rect.fromLTWH(28.0, k * 10, 49.2, 39.0));
    paintText(score.toString(), Offset(horCenter, k * 50), true, k * 25);
    heighScore = score > heighScore ? score : heighScore;
  }

  @override
  update(double t) {
    tissueBox.update(t);
    timePass -= gameing || gameover ? t : 0;
    if (timePass < 0 && gameing) {
      tissueBox.isAway = true;
      gameing = false;
      timePass = 2;
      gameover = true;
      saveHighScore();
      tissueBox.newGame();
    } else if (gameing && !gameover) {
      var floor = timePass.floor();
      if (floor < timePassTemp && floor < 6 && floor != 0)
        TissueBox.delay(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () => GameTable.tickTock.resume());
      timePassTemp = floor;
    }
    gameover = timePass <= 0 && gameover ? false : gameover;
  }

  resize(s) {
    screenSize = s;
    tileSize = screenSize.width / 9;
  }

  onDragStart(DragStartDetails detail) {
    var point = detail.globalPosition;
    dragState = tissueBox.tissue.rect.contains(point) ? Drag.tissue : tissueBox.boxRect.contains(point) ? Drag.box : Drag.none;
    initialPoint = Offset(point.dx == 0 ? initialPoint.dx : point.dx, point.dy == 0 ? initialPoint.dy : point.dy);
    point1 = (tissueBox.tissue.rect.left - point.dx).abs();
  }

  onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails detail) {
    if (gameover || dragState == Drag.none) return;
    var point = detail.globalPosition;
    destPoint = Offset(point.dx == 0 ? destPoint.dx : point.dx, point.dy == 0 ? destPoint.dy : point.dy);
    if (dragState == Drag.tissue) {
      if (initialPoint.dy - destPoint.dy > 100) {
        if (gameing != true && gameover != true) {
          gameing = true;
          timePass = 10;
          score = 0;
        }
        var sub = (point1 - (tissueBox.tissue.rect.left - point.dx).abs()).abs();
        var addPoint = sub < 3 ? 3 : sub < 6 ? 2 : 1;
        dragState = Drag.none;
        tissueBox.nextTissue(addPoint);
        playTissueAudio(addPoint);
        score += addPoint;
      }
    } else if (dragState == Drag.box) {
      tissueBox.boxRect = Rect.fromLTWH(tissueBox.initialLeft + destPoint.dx - initialPoint.dx, tissueBox.boxRect.top, TissueBox.boxSize.dx, TissueBox.boxSize.dy);
      tissueBox.ismoving = true;
    }
  }

  playTissueAudio(i) => (i == 1 ? GameTable.tissue1 : i == 2 ? GameTable.tissue2 : GameTable.tissue3).resume();
  onDragEnd(DragEndDetails detail) {
    initialPoint = Offset.zero;
    dragState = Drag.none;
    tissueBox.tissue.isMoving = false;
    tissueBox.ismoving = false;
    destPoint = initialPoint;
  }
}

class TissueBox {
  Rect get initialRect => Rect.fromLTWH(boxRect.center.dx - Tissue.width / 2, boxRect.top - boxRect.height + 20.3, Tissue.width, Tissue.width);
  Sprite get getBoxSprite =>Sprite(  rnd.nextInt(7).toString());
  var tissueAwayList = List<TissueAway>(), rnd = Random(), ismoving = false, isAway = false;
  Offset get getTissueUpPosition => Offset(initialRect.left, initialRect.top - 150);
  final GameTable game;
  Sprite boxSprite;
  Rect boxRect;
  int tissueCount;
  Tissue tissue;
  double get initialLeft => game.screenSize.width / 2 - TissueBox.boxSize.dx / 2;
  double get initialTop => game.screenSize.height - game.tileSize * 5.5;
  static var boxSize = Offset(150.0, 100.0); 
  TissueBox(this.game) {
    boxRect = Rect.fromLTWH(initialLeft, initialTop, boxSize.dx, boxSize.dy);
    tissueCount = 10 - rnd.nextInt(5);
    tissue = Tissue(game, this);
    boxSprite = getBoxSprite;
  }
  render(Canvas c) {
    boxSprite.renderRect(c, boxRect);
    tissue.render(c);
    tissueAwayList.forEach((x) => x.render(c));
  }

  update(double t) {
    tissue.update(t);
    tissueAwayList.removeWhere((x) => x.isAway);
    tissueAwayList.forEach((x) => x.update(t));
    var distense = boxRect.left - initialLeft;
    if (ismoving && !game.gameover) {
      if (distense.abs() > 50 && tissueCount == 0){
        isAway = true;
      } 
    } else if (isAway && !game.gameover) {
      boxRect = boxRect.shift(Offset(distense > 0 ? boxRect.left + game.k * 11 : boxRect.left - game.k * 11, boxRect.top));
      if (boxRect.right < -50 || boxRect.left > game.screenSize.width + 50) {
        newBox();
      }
    } else if (isAway && game.gameover) {
      var target = Offset(boxRect.left, game.screenSize.height + Tissue.width) - Offset(boxRect.left, boxRect.top);
      boxRect = boxRect.shift(
        game.k * 11 < target.distance ? 
            Offset.fromDirection(target.direction, game.k * 11)
          : target);
    } else {
      var target = Offset(initialLeft, initialTop) - Offset(boxRect.left, boxRect.top);
      boxRect = boxRect.shift(
        game.k * 11 < target.distance ? 
          Offset.fromDirection(target.direction, game.k * 11)
          : target);
    }
  }

  nextTissue(int pointsAdd) {
    var duration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    tissueAwayList.add(TissueAway(game, this));
    if (pointsAdd > 1)
      delay(duration, () {
        tissueAwayList.add(TissueAway(game, this));
        if (pointsAdd > 2)
          delay(duration, () {
            tissueAwayList.add(TissueAway(game, this));
          });
      });
    tissue = Tissue(game, this, --tissueCount == 0);
  }

  newBox() {
    boxSprite = getBoxSprite;
    boxRect = Rect.fromLTWH(boxRect.right < -0 ? game.screenSize.width + 50 - boxSize.dx : -50.0, initialTop, boxSize.dx, boxSize.dy);
    tissueCount = 10 - rnd.nextInt(5);
    tissue = Tissue(game, this);
    isAway = false;
    ismoving = false;
  }

  newGame() async {
    isAway = true;
    GameTable.gameOver.resume();
    await delay(Duration(seconds: 2), () {});
    newBox();
  }

  static delay(duration, func()) async => await Future.delayed(duration, func);
}

class Tissue {
  var tissueSprite = Sprite('t'), isMoving = false;
  static var width = 100.0;
  final TissueBox tissueBox;
  final GameTable game;
  bool isAway;
  Rect rect;
  Tissue(this.game, this.tissueBox, [this.isAway = false]) {
    rect = tissueBox.initialRect;
  }
  render(Canvas c) => tissueSprite.renderRect(c, rect);
  update(double t) => rect = isAway ? rect.shift(Offset.infinite) : tissueBox.initialRect;
}

class TissueAway extends Tissue {
  TissueAway(GameTable game, TissueBox tissueBox) : super(game, tissueBox);
  render(Canvas c) => tissueSprite.renderRect(c, rect);
  update(double t) {
    var speed = 500 * t;
    Offset target = tissueBox.getTissueUpPosition - Offset(rect.left, rect.top);
    if (speed < target.distance)
      rect = rect.shift(Offset.fromDirection(target.direction, speed));
    else
      isAway = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the `main` method will have a line that says `runApp(...)`. The value of the `...` is a widget that will be treated as the root widget of the app. In theory, you could just take that widget and pass it to your `Navigator.push` method and it should treat that widget as any other widget.

That being said, real life probably won't be as clean as this. There might be some initialization code in that app's `main` method or root widget that won't work properly if the app has long since already been initialized. Since virtually every Flutter app's root widget creates a `WidgetsApp` (or one of its derived classes `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp`), there might be some conflict that arrives from having one of those widgets being inserted as a descendent of another one of those widgets.

The game in question may work simply, or it might take some tweaking to work properly. That's something that will depend entirely on what app you are trying to embed into your own, so the only solution is to try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: I changed and tried a few things that I've mentioned in my edit. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @SimranAswani Like I said, you pass whatever is in the `runApp(...)` call to your navigator.

Comment: I tried calling runapp(game.widget) but it didn't seem to work. Anything else I could try?

Comment: So what I tried was I defined a function:
 void hello()async{

var game = GameTable((await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getInt('hs') ?? 0);
  runApp(game.widget);
} 

and I called *hello()*. This showed me the the game but it wasn't working. 
So then I tried to call tissuemain() in the Navigator. push() part and the game showed up and was functional but it showed me a null error while loading the game.

Comment: @SimranAswani Follow the null error. Eventually you'll find out what you're missing.

Comment: this is what its showing me in the the debug console: The builder for route "null" returned null.

Comment: @SimranAswani It's not readily clear what the problem is. It could be related to the nested navigator, _your_ app's navigator, how you're building the route in `Navigator.push`, or something else. Embedding an app inside another app is a delicate process, and you're bound to run into snags.

Comment: okay so I called both the *hello()* function as well as the *tissuemain()* function in the Navigator.push() part and it solved may problem! thanks!